# É possível criar um botão que faça a pessoa adicionar o site na tela do celular?

Tags: javascript, html

Existe no Android e no iOS um atalho que adiciona o site em sua tela do celular, como um aplicativo, tem como eu fazer um botão que faça isso?

Answer (score 1):

Sim. Mas depende da implementação dos navegadores do service worker ([ver aqui](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/)) e do suporte a [manifestos web](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/).

O Chrome é o único a dar suporte a ambos:

- O site deve ter sido visitado mais de uma vez, com mais de 5 minutos de diferença.
- Registre um `service worker`:

  ```
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    console.log("Will the service worker register?");
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
      .then(function(reg){
        console.log("Service worker registrado.");
      });
  }
  ```
- Os site dever ser HTTPS (por causa do `service worker`).
- Deve ter um [manifesto web app](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/) como nesse exemplo (os atributos são obrigatórios):

  ```
  {
    "short_name": "AirHorner",
    "name": "Kinlan's AirHorner of Infamy",
    "icons": [
      {
        "src": "launcher-icon-1x.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "48x48"
      },
      {
        "src": "launcher-icon-2x.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "96x96"
      },
      {
        "src": "launcher-icon-4x.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "192x192"
      }
   ],
   "start_url": "index.html?launcher=true"
  }
  ```

Você pode adicionar um evento `onclick` em um botão:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", ev => { 
  ev.preventDefault();
  addHomeScreenBotao.onclick = () => ev.prompt();
});
```

---

Para outros navegadores tem bibliotecas para simular essa funcionalidade:
https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen